# Display an image according to the moon phase

Tags: php

I'd like to know if it's possible to calculate the current moon phase or get it from somewhere (www, rss, I don't know..) in PHP.

Basically I need to display an image in a website depending on the current moon phase.

I found this: http://jivebay.com/2010/01/04/calculating-the-moon-phase-part-2/ , however, the author says it's not 100% accurate.

Any ideas ? thanks!

Comment: nothing is 100% accurate.  In any case for anything to be accurate you need to include all the terms in the lunar theory given by Chapront (ELP2000/82) in their book "Lunar Tables and Programs from 4000 B.C. to A.D. 8000".  They discuss their theory and their programs to produce it, all 200 000 terms.  In any case for that accuracy its not necessary to use that precision, and acceptable low-precision/middle-precision is probably more than adequate - so 100% accuracy is probably beyond what would be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to use an RSS feed, why don't you calculate the current phase yourself like explained here: [Calculate Moon Phase Data with PHP](http://www.obsid.org/2008/05/calculate-moon-phase-data-with-php.html) which is referencing this [Moon Phase PHP class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1201-PHP-Calculates-the-phase-of-the-Moon.html).

Answer (score 7):

```
// calculate lunar phase (1900 - 2199)
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('n');
$day = date('j');
if ($month < 4) {$year = $year - 1; $month = $month + 12;}
$days_y = 365.25 * $year;
$days_m = 30.42 * $month;
$julian = $days_y + $days_m + $day - 694039.09;
$julian = $julian / 29.53;
$phase = intval($julian);
$julian = $julian - $phase;
$phase = round($julian * 8 + 0.5);
if ($phase == 8) {$phase = 0;}
$phase_array = array('new', 'waxing crescent', 'first quarter', 'waxing gibbous', 'full', 'waning gibbous', 'last quarter', 'waning crescent');
$lunar_phase = $phase_array[$phase];
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty accurate: http://www.calculatorcat.com/moon_phases/phasenow.php

Just HTML scrape it!